# How to return file from API to FrontEnd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to API Genarate excel file and then return file back to FrontEnd.
Either will do between display popup for download or automatic download.

This is API Code

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/ExportToExcelV1")]
public HttpResponseMessage ExportToExcelV1()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) 
    { 
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray()) 
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") 
    { 
        FileName = $"ABC-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.xlsx" 
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    return result;
}
```

This is FrontEnd Code

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportToExcelV1()
{
    var apiUrl = "https://localhost:7057/Excel/api/ExportToExcelV1";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var requestUri = apiUrl;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri) { Content = content };
            var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
    return Ok("pass");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the file inside the client server?  or you want to store the file from user client's browser?  According to your example codes, you get it from the controller backend. If you want to let the user download it, one possible way is directly add a link at view  to let the user click and directly dowanload it from the api .

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use something like EPPlus to create an Excel file to download

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/ExportToExcelV1")]
public HttpResponseMessage ExportToExcelV1()
{
    // Create a new Excel package
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        // Add a worksheet to the package
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        // Add some sample data to the worksheet
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Header1";
        worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Data1";

        // Save the package to the MemoryStream
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(package.GetAsByteArray());

        // Create the HttpResponseMessage with the Excel data
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
        };

        // Set the file name for download
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = $"ABC-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.xlsx"
        };

        // Set the content type
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Frontend code

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportToExcelV1()
{
    var apiUrl = "https://localhost:7057/Excel/api/ExportToExcelV1";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            // Create a Blob from the content
            var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

            // Create an anchor element
            var a = document.createElement('a');

            // Set the download attribute and href for the anchor element
            a.download = fileName;
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            // Append the anchor element to the document
            document.body.appendChild(a);

            // Programmatically click the anchor element
            a.click();

            // Remove the anchor element from the document
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    }

    return Ok("pass");
}
```